# Replacing a word in any given file using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am not hands on in VB Script.

I have a scenario that i have a .ini file which resides in C:\widows\ . I just need to replace  Line no 2 with computer name.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\Windows\your.ini"

text = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll, vbNewLine)
text(1) = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2).Write Join(text, vbNewLine)
```